# Nginx: load a default file if index.html doesn't exist?

Tags: nginx

Here's what I have now:

```
     location /tools {
            alias /var/www/tools/public;

            if (-f $uri) {
                    break;
            }
            if (-f "${uri}index.html") {
                    break;
            }
            if (-f $uri/index.html) {
                    break;
            }

            rewrite ^(/tools/[^/]+/).*$ $1default.html last;

            error_page 404 /tools/default.html;
    }
```

I want to make it so if you go to `/tools/module/`, it checks if `/tools/module/index.html` exists. If so, it breaks and loads the `index.html`. If not, check if `/tools/module/default.html` exists. If so, load that file and it'll do client-side routing. Otherwise, load `/tools/default.html`.

However, I'm getting:

```
rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/tools/module/default.html", request: "GET /tools/module/ HTTP/1.1"
```

Since `/tools/module/index.html` exist, it shouldn't be checking `default.html`.

`try_files` never worked for me, I wasted hours trying to get it to work. I think it's because I'm using `alias`, which doesn't work well with `try_files`.

Edit:

These didn't work either:

```
rewrite ^(/tools/[^/]+)/.*(?<!(index\.html|dynamic\.html)))$ $1/dynamic.html last;

rewrite ^(/tools/[^/]+)/(?!.*(index\.html|dynamic\.html)))$ $1/dynamic.html last;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it the default behavior of your site either at the http or server level, then override it with locations as needed:

```
error_page  404 /tools/default.html;
index   index.html default.html;
```